# Sole developer handling multiple code changes

Tags: c#, .net

In a low budget single developer situation, how would you handle multiple code changes at once.

For example, the developer may be working on a new feature that requires database changes. During that time a bug is reported and its a simple code change. Deployment of the code would require deployment of the incomplete new web app feature and database change.

In a multi-developer environment, you could have one developer fork the fix code and another the new feature code.

How would you do similar in a single developer environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use feature branches (you are using source control aren't you?).

The basic strategy with source control is that whenever you deploy to production, you add a tag (named label in some systems) so that in the situation you describe, you can put aside your new feature work, create a new branch off the latest tag and release the fix without getting new half-done code deployed.

Comment: I use source control but I'm not a sole developer. You answered exactly as I suspected. I can now advise correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Git. Git is a decentralized source version control system. You would have your master branch which contains the latest released version of the code. When you are starting work on a new feature, you create a new branch based on the master branch. When you're done you integrate your work back into the master branch. When you need to do a fix, you create a new branch, and then integrate it back into your master branch. Git is very good with merging and allows your to automatically merge different versions without too many conflicts.

More information on Git and online tutorials can be found here:

http://git-scm.com/

Comment: Yep, Git or any other source control system really. Git is excellent but there are many others that are not any worse. Usually it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Mercurial is another great option. Everything except SVN/CVS. Those a horrible with this development pattern since they make entire copies of files and automatic merging always fails.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there's only one developer and one branch, you should use version control, for backup and history for example. I live in the SVN world, what I say applies there but it's not that different elsewhere. In your situation, when you ship a stable release, put that in a release branch, fix bugs in it, and develop new stuff in the trunk. You can even develop many features at once with feature branches.